# Salvar uma tabela de frequência em um arquivo. (compactador huffman)

Tags: java, compressão

Olá,

Eu estou desenvolvendo um trabalho de algoritmo de Huffman, e estou com certa dificuldade para trabalhar com a tabela de frequencia.
Resumindo, eu preciso transformar os caracteres de um texto em uma tabela de frequencia para criar a arvore de huffman.

exemplo: abacaxi...
A tabela tem que ter:

```
 a = 3
 b = 1
 c = 1
 x = 1
 i = 1
```

Eu estou usando esse codigo:

```
int[] charFreqs = new int[256];
    for (char c : test.toCharArray())
        charFreqs[c]++;
```

Ele cria a tabela e é possivel montar a arvore dessa forma:

```
    public static HuffmanTree buildTree(int[] charFreqs) {
    // Cria uma Fila de Prioridade 
    // A Fila será criado pela ordem de frequência da letra no texto
    PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree> trees = new PriorityQueue<HuffmanTree>();
    // Criar as Folhas da Árvore para cada letra 
    for (int i = 0; i < charFreqs.length; i++){
        if (charFreqs[i] > 0)
            trees.offer(new HuffmanLeaf(charFreqs[i], (char)i)); // Inser os elementos, nó folha, na fila de prioridade
    }
    // Percorre todos os elementos da fila
    // Criando a árvore binária de baixo para cima
    while (trees.size() > 1) {
        // Pega os dois nós com menor frequência
        HuffmanTree a = trees.poll(); // poll - Retorna o próximo nó da Fila ou NULL se não tem mais
        HuffmanTree b = trees.poll(); // poll - Retorna o próximo nó da Fila ou NULL se não tem mais

        // Criar os nós da árvore binária
        trees.offer(new HuffmanNode(a, b)); 
    }
    // Retorna o primeiro nó da árvore
    return trees.poll();
```

o problema é que para eu descompactar um arquivo, é preciso ler essa tabela novamente e recriar a arvore, então é necessário salvar ela em um arquivo texto ou qualquer outra forma, eu estou tentando com txt... porem quando eu leio o txt e tento montar a tabela novamente, a arvore não é remontada, ela fica vazia...

Eu usei esse programa como base: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J3IzsJPySmd0FzNzBVeGdtdGM/view

Alguém poderia me ajudar? talvez tenha alguma coisa que eu não tenha entendido...

Comment: Pode colocar o código de r/w do seu txt aqui? Não consigo acessar o drive.

Comment: Não entendi o seu problema. O que exatamente você não está conseguindo fazer? Eu peguei o seu código e fiz um exemplo utilizando dados de um arquivo txt. O algoritmo funcionou normalmente.